# Sync Local site and Distant site

Tags: localhost, git, github

I want to manage my WP site in local, then sync it to my git, and then automatically deploy it.
In fact, I already have my site in production, and trying to make it work in local.
The fact is I can make it work in local, but every link send me to the distant domain : mydomain.com instead of managing localhost.

How should I manage it???

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to update the database to replace the guids and base URL.

I recommend WP Migrate DB Pro to quickly sync two databases. Otherwise you need to run a few SQL statements to find and replace the old domain with the new domain. In PHPMyAdmin run the following statements from the SQL window. Replace old-domain with your exact distant domain, and the new-domain with your complete local address.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Doing so will solve 90% of your link issues.

Comment: Well, I'm in the 10%, I ran the query, but nothing changed. I will see the WP Migrate DB Pro, it sounds great !

Comment: what does it list as your url in General Settings area?

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working, I've updated wp-config.php and added 2 lines :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/mylocalsite');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/mylocalsite');
```

Tx !